# Promise node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promises

Faço 3 requisições HTTPS nodejs para uma API também em node, cada promise executa uma tarefa e essas promises estou passando várias informações no body delas, uma dessas informações precisa ser um ID. Executando uma promise all, com as 3 promises, a promise example_2 me retorna um ID e quero passar esse ID para a promise example_3, me retornando o resultado que preciso. Então o resultado do promise all tem que ser da promise example_3. E não faço ideia de como fazer isso!

```
let example_3 = () =>{
   return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>{
     try{
        request({
            method:'post',
            body:'AQUI PRECISO DO ID DO EXAMPLE_2'
       },error(.....


//Executo todas promises
let exect = async () => { 
   let responses    = await Promise.all([example_1,example_2,example_3])
   let responseJson = JSON.parse(responses[1]);
   //o id da promise example_2
   let idExample2   = JSON.parse(responseJson.data.filter_value);
}
```

O id que eu quero passar para a promise EXAMPLE_2 esta na variavel idResp. Alguém poderia me orientar?

Comment: tenta melhorar o corpo da sua pergunta, qual tecnologia você utiliza, é um banco? um documento JSON? isso não está claro deixe toda informação possível.
qual tipo de banco de for um banco e o que exatamente tem nesse modelo de banco, tudo isso tem que ser passado.

Comment: obrigado @Teuuz1994, vou melhorar a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ja que está usando async / await você não pode fazer dessa maneira ?

```
let example_3 = (id) =>{
   return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>{
     try{
        request({
            method:'post',
            body: id
       },error(.....


//Executo todas promises
let exect = async () => { 
   let promise1 = await example_1()
   let promise2 = await example_2()

   let promise3 = await example_3(promise2.data.filter_value)
}
```

Você também pode paralelizar as chamadas para melhorar a performance.

```
let exect = async () => { 
       let promise2 = await example_2()

       let promise1 = example_1()
       let promise3 = example_3(promise2.data.filter_value)

       let responsePromise1 = await promise1
       let responsePromise3 = await promise3

    }
```

Comment: obrigado, com seu exemplo me deu uma luz, declarei uma variavel global e joguei o id dentro dela. ficou assim:  
state.myId = JSON.parse(responseJson.data.filter_value);  
let examp = await example_3();